# Ruby Battleships

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am testing my grid and i have realized that row 0 cannot be coloured in. please help!

```
require 'colorize'

def board
  puts "enter the x co-ordinate"  
  x_input = gets.chomp.to_i  
  puts "enter the y co-ordiante"  
  y_input = gets.chomp.to_i    

  arr = Array.new(10, ".").map{|y| Array.new(10, ".")}

  y_axis = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  x_axis = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

  print "\t"
  print y_axis.join("\t")
  puts

  arr.each_with_index do |y, i|
    print x_axis[i]
    print "\t"
    print y.join("\t")
    for y_coordinate in y_input..y_input
      for x_coordinate in x_input..x_input
        arr[y_coordinate][x_coordinate]= " ".colorize(:color => :light_blue, :background => :red)
      end
    end
    puts
  end 
  puts
end
board
```

Comment: Here's some advice that can help you find your glitch: add `x_min=0; x_max=9; y_min=0; y_max=9` then rewrite your loops such as `for y in y_min..y_max`

Answer (score 0):

You're printing row `0` before adding the colored tile to the array.
Also, you don't need the nested `for` loops (you only have one element).
Try with:

```
arr.each_with_index do |y, i|
  print x_axis[i]
  print "\t"
  arr[y_input][x_input]= " ".colorize(:color => :light_blue, :background => :red)
  print y.join("\t")
  puts
end
```